# Json.NET Custom JsonConverter with data types

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I stumbled upon a service that outputs JSON in the following format:

```
{
    "Author": "me",
    "Version": "1.0.0",
    "data.Type1": {
        "Children": [
            {
                "data.Type1": {
                    "Children": [
                        {
                            "data.Type2": {
                                "name": "John",
                                "surname": "Doe"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "data.Type3": {
                    "dob": "1990-01-01"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Data type names are preserved as property names and their values are the actual objects. They all start with a `data.` prefix.

What I'd like to get afterwards is something like this:

```
{ // Root
    "Author": "me",
    "Version": "1.0.0",
    "Children": [ // Type1
        {
            "Children": [ // Type1
                { // Type2
                    "Name": "John",
                    "Surname": "Doe"
                }
            ]
        },
        { // Type3
            "DoB": "1990-01-01"
        }
    ]
}
```

with the following classes:

```
class Type1 {
    ICollection<object> Children { get; set; }
}

class Type2 {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}

class Type3 {
    public DateTime DoB { get; set; }
}

class Root 
{
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public Type1 Children { get; set; }
}
```

**Question**

How can I deserialize this into added C# classes, taking into account the data types and removing them from the tree?

I've tried with a custom `JsonConverter`, but am struggling with how to dynamically choose the converter, since the easiest way would be to put an attribute on the property, but it is not supported.

A small example would be great.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although this JSON format is somewhat unusual and resists the use of attributes due to the dynamic property names, it is still possible to make a `JsonConverter` to deserialize it into your preferred class structure with one small change: I would recommend you change the `Children` property in the `Root` class to be an `ICollection<object>` to mirror the `Children` property in the `Type1` class.  As it is now, it does not match the structure of your desired output (where `Children` is shown as an array, not an object) and would otherwise require additional code in the converter to handle properly.

```
class Root
{
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public ICollection<object> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Here is what I came up with for the converter (assuming the above change is made):

```
class CustomConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(Root));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);
        Root root = new Root();
        root.Author = (string)obj["Author"];
        root.Version = (string)obj["Version"];
        root.Children = ((Type1)DeserializeTypeX(obj, serializer)).Children;
        return root;
    }

    private object DeserializeTypeX(JObject obj, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JProperty prop = obj.Properties().Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("data.")).First();
        JObject child = (JObject)prop.Value;
        if (prop.Name == "data.Type1")
        {
            List<object> children = new List<object>();
            foreach (JObject jo in child["Children"].Children<JObject>())
            {
                children.Add(DeserializeTypeX(jo, serializer));
            }
            return new Type1 { Children = children };
        }
        else if (prop.Name == "data.Type2")
        {
            return child.ToObject<Type2>(serializer);
        }
        else if (prop.Name == "data.Type3")
        {
            return child.ToObject<Type3>(serializer);
        }
        throw new JsonSerializationException("Unrecognized type: " + prop.Name);
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Armed with this converter you can deserialize to your classes like this:

```
Root root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json, new CustomConverter());
```

You can then serialize to the new format like this:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd",
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented
};

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, settings));
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ESNMLE

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work but have you tried using Newtonsoft.Json to serialize the object and include JsonProperty tags on the class properties? I know this will work when deserializing Json into a class.

```
<JsonProperty("user_id")>
Public Property UserID As String
//Converts Json {user_id: 123} to class.UserID = 123
```

To Serialize with Newtonsoft, first include Newtonsoft into the project then

```
Dim stringJson As String = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root)
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I tried, but the problem is, that entire levels must be removed and replaced, because they only serve as data to distinguish which type they represent, where JsonProperty is only to map between class name and json property name.