# (De)serialization of BSON data of potentially nested objects with specific structure

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, julia, bson

### TL;DR

I am trying to (de-)serialize BSON data from/to Julia/C#, some libraries know how to write and read this in each language, but I can't figure how to translate things between the two implementations.

It feels like a Json.net JSON Converter should be used but I do not see how to configure it without rewriting a converter for every single type.

I do not expect a complete answer, but helpful pointers will be gratefully appreciated !

Addition : Here is a somewhat close topic [Json.NET Custom JsonConverter with data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36969500/json-net-custom-jsonconverter-with-data-types).

### Context

##### Project

I am currently working on a communication between a computation kernel using julia and a .net program that serves as a graphical interface.
To be able to share quite complex datasets between the two programs, I looked for a data format that

- is supported in both languages,
- is flexible enough to handle heavy data (such as ND arrays of complex number)

After trying MsgPack (that unfortunately does not work for ND arrays yet, ouch !), I am now testing BSON as a serialization format.

My goal is to be able to handle multiple custom types, without rewriting everything every time.

##### Available libraries

In julia, there is a [BSON.jl](https://github.com/JuliaIO/BSON.jl) package which writes and read pretty much everything, so let's assume it can handle anything I throw at him.

In C#, which is the main object of this question, there is the seemingly obvious choice of [JSON.net BSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeToBson.htm) serializer.

##### Problem

Despite the available code, the julia serializer writes information that of course Json.net cannot serialize to or deserialize from natively.
So after reading quite a lot of posts here and there, it appears a custom `JsonConverter<T>` is required to achieve my goal.

A lot of posts seems to be already available to do this but :

- I've never done something like this in C# (or any other language for that matter)
- I am not sure where to start from to avoid unnecessary code repetition

##### Data sample

To server as an example, here is a JSON conversion of a BSON file generated with the julia package. The conversion was performed with https://json-bson-converter.appspot.com/

```
{
    "dict": {
        "tag": "struct",
        "type": {
            "tag": "datatype",
            "params": [
                {
                    "tag": "datatype",
                    "params": [],
                    "name": [
                        "Core",
                        "Any"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "tag": "datatype",
                    "params": [],
                    "name": [
                        "Core",
                        "Any"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "name": [
                "Main",
                "Base",
                "Dict"
            ]
        },
        "data": [
            [
                "string",
                "arr",
                "vec",
                "cplxvec",
                "scal"
            ],
            [
                "blablabla",
                {
                    "tag": "array",
                    "type": {
                        "tag": "datatype",
                        "params": [],
                        "name": [
                            "Core",
                            "Int8"
                        ]
                    },
                    "size": [
                        2,
                        3
                    ],
                    "data": "683oIbTI"
                },
                {
                    "tag": "array",
                    "type": {
                        "tag": "datatype",
                        "params": [],
                        "name": [
                            "Core",
                            "Int8"
                        ]
                    },
                    "size": [
                        4
                    ],
                    "data": "KxgCgA=="
                },
                {
                    "tag": "array",
                    "type": {
                        "tag": "datatype",
                        "params": [
                            {
                                "tag": "datatype",
                                "params": [],
                                "name": [
                                    "Core",
                                    "Float64"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "name": [
                            "Main",
                            "Base",
                            "Complex"
                        ]
                    },
                    "size": [
                        3
                    ],
                    "data": "bODExAuj5D9SoKEy0NDqP4jU3buU8+k/tFNpqcmh7z+miGD4H87oPyKwK7BUEuo/"
                },
                33.6
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

As far as I can analyze the contents of this file, I see :

- A scalar type is converted with a somewhat native format
- Other types are converted to dictionary-like structures with the following properties

  - a `tag` field composed of a single `string`
  - a `type` field which has a specific format depending on the contents of `tag`
  - a `data` field encoded in a binary format
  - an optional `size` field (once again based on the contents of `tag`
- A `type` field is characterized by the following properties

  - a `tag` as before
  - a `params` field that may be

    - empty (if the element type is a primitive type)
    - a list of types (otherwise)
  - a `name` field that lists type names from julia

##### Custom converter

I know that to make a custom Converter, an starting point is the following, based on e.g. [here](https://blog.maskalik.com/asp-net/json-net-implement-custom-serialization/) :

```
public class JuliaObjectSerializer : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

However, I really do not know what to define there to be generic and versatile enough to read all the information from my source file.
My first thought was to define some structures to receive the information, such as

```
public static class JuliaComm
{
 public struct JuliaObject
        {
            public string tag { get; set; }
            public JuliaType type { get; set; }
            public long size { get; set; }
            public sbyte data { get; set; }
        }

        public struct JuliaType
        {
            public string tag { get; set; }
            public List<JuliaType> param { get; set; }
            public List<string> name { get; set; }
            public JuliaType(string tag, List<JuliaType> param, List<string> name)
            {
                this.tag = tag;
                this.param = param;
                this.name = name;
            }
        }
    }

    internal sealed class JuliaObjectConverter : JsonConverter
    {

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            var type = objectType.GetElementType();
            var isarr = objectType.IsArray;
            return isarr && (type == typeof(Array) || type == typeof(double) || type == typeof(Complex) || type == typeof(long));
        }
        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
            {
                JObject item = JObject.Load(reader);
                if (item["tag"] != null)
                {
                    var tag = item["tag"].ToString();
                    if (tag == "struct")
                    {
                        var type = item["type"].ToObject<JuliaComm.JuliaType>();
                        var data = item["data"]; // to something else ?


                        
                    }
                    else if (tag == "array")
                    {
                        var type = item["type"].ToObject<JuliaComm.JuliaType>();
                        var size = item["size"].ToObject<int[]>();
                        var arr = Array.CreateInstance(type, size);
                        if (type["param"] == [])
                        {
                           // fill array with byte to type converter ?;
                        }


                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (value.GetType().IsClass)
            {
                writer.WriteStartObject();
                writer.WritePropertyName(value.ToString()); // should be the name of the variable
                writer.WritePropertyName("tag");
                writer.WriteValue("struct");
                writer.WritePropertyName("type");
                // serializer.Serialize(writer,); // should be a  List<JuliaType> converion of all types in class
                writer.WriteValue("data");
                // serializer.Serialize(writer,); // should be a something ! not clear yet
                writer.WriteEndObject();
            }
            else if (value.GetType().IsArray)
            {

            }
        }
    }

    internal sealed class JuliaTypeConverter : JsonConverter
    {

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return (objectType == typeof(JuliaComm.JuliaType));
        }
        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            JObject jsonObject = JObject.Load(reader);
            var tag = "datatype";
            var type = jsonObject["type"].ToObject<JuliaComm.JuliaType>();
            var param = jsonObject["params"].ToObject<List<JuliaComm.JuliaType>>();
            var name = jsonObject["name"].ToObject<List<string>>();
            return new JuliaComm.JuliaType(tag, param, name);
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
            var jtype = value as JuliaComm.JuliaType;
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            writer.WritePropertyName("tag");
            serializer.Serialize(writer,"datatype");
            writer.WritePropertyName("params");
            serializer.Serialize(writer, jtype.param);
            writer.WritePropertyName("name");
            serializer.Serialize(writer, jtype.name);
            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
    }
```

but it might be totally inappropriate (I get static errors).

I know all the primitive type conversions between julia and C#, so using the information in the file to infer the C# types won't be an issue.

Sorry for the long post, I just wanted to be as clear as possible, though I surely forgot something.

Comment: tl;dr but how can BSON data not deserialized by .NET or Julia if they use the same format for data exchange? The point of having a shared format is to do the exchange between systems possibly using different technologies

Comment: @Phate01, I am just as surprised as you are... I just guess sharing the same serialization specification does not mean serializing data the same way. More precisely, delimiters are identical as well as primitive types, but anything else is a whole other story.

Comment: Even the last array of your data, the one where the first element is `blablabla`, seems composed by data of different types (string, then 2 objects, then a double), so you're going to need a custom converter. What problems do you have with the code you posted?

Comment: @Phate01, my main concern is that I have custom classes declared in both languages that comprise several fields, of potentially nested objects, so i would like to use the intermediate `JuliaType` and `JuliaObject` classes to guide the converter. Right now I just feel like I have to create a converter that covers any case, even for primitive types...
I was hoping for pointers regarding the strategy to tackle this, but with little success so far it appears.

Comment: I would consider the BSON -> JSON -> CSV -> JSON -> BSON conversion path, with no binary blobs in the CSV, which should be doable in both languages.  If it is not, you have found your problem by comparing the text format variables in CSV made by Julia and C#.

Comment: @Bill I am sorry, but I do not follow you logic, why would it be useful to convert binary data from the BSON to a text format such as CSV ?

Answer (score 0):

Going from JSON to CSV flattens the data structures and if binaries are excluded makes sure there are not any incompatible binary structures left in the data. This should reveal any hidden incompatibilities in the JSON by changing how they map to CSV.