# C# convert Complex array to byte array in Json.net

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, bson

Following up on this question [(De)serialization of BSON data of potentially nested objects with specific structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67886403/deserialization-of-bson-data-of-potentially-nested-objects-with-specific-struc?noredirect=1#comment120068691_67886403), I need to be able to (de-)serialize arrays of `Complex` numbers from/to C#.

Currently, I am using a Json.net JsonConverter which involves multiple cases where I test against properties recursively, which works fine at the moment.

The data exposed in the BSON is a byte array when large datasets are involved. Assuming I can get it with

```
var data = obj["data"].ToObject<byte[]>();
```

I need to be able to convert this to the following cases when appropriate

- an array of primitives
- an array of `Complex`
- an array of arrays

all arrays may be understood as n-dimensional arrays.

When the element type is a primitive, there is my approach for de-serialization (but the approach for serialization follows the same organization) :

```
// etype is the element type of the array
// dimensions contains the length of the array in each dimension
var result = Array.CreateInstance(etype,dimensions);
var length = result.Length;
Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, result, 0, data.Length);
```

However, this doesn't work anymore when dealing with non-primitives. Which leads to the following approach for `Complex` numbers : create a buffer variable `temp` that holds the real + imaginary parts of my complex numbers, then fill the actual array with the `Complex`.

```
var temp = new double[2 * length];
Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, temp, 0, data.Length);
// Complex[] case
if (dimensions.Length == 1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dimensions[0]; i++)
    {
        result.SetValue(new Complex(temp[2 * i], temp[2 * i + 1]), i);
    }
    return result;
}
// for 2D/3D arrays, additional for loops
```

I am not that much used to C# but this feels wrong in multiple places :

- using a buffer variable,
- needing a growing level of nested loops

So my question is : is there a way to simplify / improve this implementation so as to

- avoid code repetition
- avoid allocating temporary array

Comment: Why are you serializing your data as a `byte[]` array rather than serializing it according to the BSON format?  Can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: @dbc I know this is not a real answer in the context of this question, and I do not mean to be rude or to diminish the value of a MWE, but if you follow the link at the beginning of my post (my previous question), you will find a complete background there.
If it is not enough, or the right information, I will add this as soon as possible (I am not at work at the moment).

Comment: @dbc Regarding you first comment though, I assumed that it was the right thing to do since the data is a byte array in the BSON, but that may be a poor choice on my part.